# how to add number to onclick url with javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, numbers

I need your help

I'm trying to add number to the onclick url number
format of code is like this

```
<div class="message">
<div class="info"><a href="/user/spox/" onclick="ShowProfile('spox', '/user/spox/');     return false;" target="_blank">spox</a></div>
</div>
```

I have in source

```
var group_id = 1;
```

which is defend on what status has user
admin, moder, publisher, user or guest
each of them has individual number
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

so I need to add by javascript number of group_id in here

```
onclick="ShowProfile('spox', '/user/spox/', '1');
```

so format of adding number should be after '/user/some user name/'
, 'group_id number'

I was trying to do this by code

```
$(function(){
attrUserA = $('.info a').attr('onclick');
attrUserA = attrUserA.split(';');
sliceUser = attrUserA[0].slice(0, -1);
attrUserA[0] = sliceUser + ", '" + group_id + "')";
attrUserA = attrUserA.join('; ');
$('.info a').attr('onclick', attrUserA);
});
```

it works, the script adds number from

```
var group_id = 1;
```

but I have problem with this, because script changes the individual urls in onclick to one
so after this if some user had link like this

```
onclick="ShowProfile('spox', '/user/spox/', 'number from group id');
```

and last message was written by user: blablabla
the individual personal urls of other users changed to

```
onclick="ShowProfile('blablabla', '/user/blablabla/', 'number from group id');
```

how can I just add number and don't touch urls?

Comment: Have you tried setting the group id seperately like so.
`onclick="ShowProfile('blablabla', '/user/blablabla/', $(this).attr('data-group'));"`.  Then in your javascript set `data-group` to be the group id.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?:

jQuery:

```
var group_id = 1;

$(function(){
    var attrUserA = $('.info a').attr('onclick');
    attrUserA = attrUserA.split(',');
    var sliceUser = attrUserA[0].slice(0, -1);
    attrUserA[0] = sliceUser + "'";
    attrUserA[1] = attrUserA[1].slice(0, -2);
    attrUserA[1] = attrUserA[1] + ", " + group_id + ");";
    attrUserA = attrUserA.join(', ');

$('.info a').attr('onclick', attrUserA);
    alert(attrUserA);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="message">
    <div class="info"><a href="/user/spox/" onclick="ShowProfile('spox', '/user/spox/');" target="_blank">spox</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Blue_EyesWhiteDragon/tpdpgttn/

Comment: no format should stay like this




    <div class="message">
    <div class="info"><a href="/user/spox/" onclick="ShowProfile('spox', '/user/spox/');     return false;" target="_blank">spox</a></div>
    </div>